# How to rotate markers individually in openlayers

Tags: javascript, rotation, openlayers, marker

I want to display on duty taxi positions using openlayers.
I have coordinates and heading of each taxi cab but when I'm trying to display them everything is okay with coordinates but headings aren't displaying properly. It's because I have the same style for every marker and adding them to the same vector layer.
I would like to show each vehicle with its own heading.
Any solutions for this issue will be appreciated.

My code:

```
    var taxiMarker = new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Icon({
           scale: 0.7, anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
           src: 'uploads/taxiMarker.png'
         })
    });
    var taxi_vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
        }),
        style: [taxiMarker]
    });

    for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
         let tCoords = res[i][0].split(',');
         let heading = parseFloat(res[i][1]);
         let marker = new ol.geom.Point(tCoords);
         let featureMarker = new ol.Feature(marker);
         taxiMarker.getImage().setRotation(heading);
         taxi_vector.getSource().addFeature(featureMarker);
    }
```

Comment: Use a style function as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wind-arrows.html instead of a static style

Comment: Thank you so much @Mike. It's exactly what I wanted to do.